Normalization inserting NaN values into my dataframe
I am doing StandardScaler normalization to my dataframe but it is inserting NaN values into some of the rows
Main Function
games = prepare_data()

train_size = int(0.7 * len(games))
test_size = len(games) - train_size
train_set = games.iloc[:train_size]
test_set = games.iloc[-test_size:]

X_train = train_set.iloc[:,:-1] 
y_train = train_set.iloc[:,-1]
X_test = test_set.iloc[:,:-1] 
y_test = test_set.iloc[:,-1]

train_set_normalized = normalize_data(train_set,'HOME_TEAM_WINS')

prepare_data
def prepare_data():

    #Import data from pkl files
    games = pd.read_pickle('cleaned_data/merged.pkl')
    teams = pd.read_pickle('cleaned_data/teams.pkl')
 
    #Add foundation year of home team
    games = games.merge(teams[['TEAM_ID', 'YEARFOUNDED']], left_on='HOME_TEAM_ID', right_on='TEAM_ID', how='left')
    games['FOUNDATION_HOME'] = games['YEARFOUNDED']
    games.drop('TEAM_ID', axis=1, inplace=True)
    games.drop('YEARFOUNDED', axis=1, inplace=True)

    #Add foundation year of away team
    games = games.merge(teams[['TEAM_ID', 'YEARFOUNDED']], left_on='VISITOR_TEAM_ID', right_on='TEAM_ID', how='left')
    games['FOUNDATION_VISITOR'] = games['YEARFOUNDED']
    games.drop('TEAM_ID', axis=1, inplace=True)
    games.drop('YEARFOUNDED', axis=1, inplace=True)

    games = games[games['SEASON'] != 2003]
    #Remove IDs and redundant columns
    # Lista das colunas que você deseja remover
    remove = [
    'GAME_DATE_EST',
    'GAME_ID',
    'HOME_TEAM_ID',
    'VISITOR_TEAM_ID',
    'SEASON',
    'HOME_TEAM_REGULAR_SEASON_GAMES',
    'HOME_TEAM_REGULAR_SEASON_TOTAL_WINS',
    'HOME_TEAM_REGULAR_SEASON_TOTAL_LOSSES',
    'HOME_TEAM_REGULAR_SEASON_WINNING_PERCENTAGE',
    'HOME_TEAM_REGULAR_SEASON_WINS_AT_HOME',
    'HOME_TEAM_REGULAR_SEASON_LOSSES_AT_HOME',
    'HOME_TEAM_REGULAR_SEASON_WINS_AWAY',
    'HOME_TEAM_REGULAR_SEASON_AWAY_LOSSES',
    'STANDINGSDATE',
    'AWAY_TEAM_REGULAR_SEASON_GAMES',
    'AWAY_TEAM_REGULAR_SEASON_TOTAL_WINS',
    'AWAY_TEAM_REGULAR_SEASON_TOTAL_LOSSES',
    'AWAY_TEAM_REGULAR_SEASON_WINNING_PERCENTAGE',
    'AWAY_TEAM_REGULAR_SEASON_WINS_AT_HOME',
    'AWAY_TEAM_REGULAR_SEASON_LOSSES_AT_HOME',
    'AWAY_TEAM_REGULAR_SEASON_WINS_AWAY',
    'AWAY_TEAM_REGULAR_SEASON_AWAY_LOSSES'
    ]

    games = games.drop(columns=remove)


    #HOME_TEAM_WINS TO LAST COLUMN
    target = games.pop('HOME_TEAM_WINS')
    games.insert(len(games.columns), 'HOME_TEAM_WINS', target)

    print(games.head(50))
    print("HOME TEAM WINS VALUE COUNTS:")
    print(games['HOME_TEAM_WINS'].value_counts())

    games.to_csv('2.csv', index=False)
    return games

normalize_data
def normalize_data(data, target_column):
    result = data.isna().sum()
    result.to_csv('nan_counts.csv', header=['NaN_count'])
    data_normalized = data.copy()

    subset = data_normalized[[
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_GAMES',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_GAMES',
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_WINS',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_WINS',
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_LOSSES',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_LOSSES',
    'HOME_TEAM_WIN_PERCENTAGE',
    'AWAY_TEAM_WIN_PERCENTAGE',
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_GAMES_AT_HOME',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_GAMES_AWAY',
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_WINS_AT_HOME',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_WINS_AWAY',
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_LOSSES_AT_HOME',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_LOSSES_AWAY',
    'HOME_TEAM_WIN_PERCENTAGE_AT_HOME',
    'AWAY_TEAM_WIN_PERCENTAGE_AWAY',
    'HOME_TEAM_WIN/LOSS_STREAK',
    'VISITOR_TEAM_WIN/LOSS_STREAK',
    'HOME_TEAM_WIN/LOSS_STREAK_AT_HOME',
    'VISITOR_TEAM_WIN/LOSS_STREAK_AWAY',
    'AVG_POINTS_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_CONCEDED_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_CONCEDED_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_ASSISTS_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_ASSISTS_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FGPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FGPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FTPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FTPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FG3PCT_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FG3PCT_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_REB_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_REB_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_CONCEDED_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_ASSISTS_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FGPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FTPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FG3PCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_REB_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_CONCEDED_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_ASSISTS_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FGPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FTPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FG3PCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_REB_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'FOUNDATION_HOME',
    'FOUNDATION_VISITOR'
    ]]

    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaler.fit(subset)
    scaled_data = scaler.transform(subset)
    scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(scaled_data, columns=[
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_GAMES',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_GAMES',
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_WINS',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_WINS',
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_LOSSES',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_LOSSES',
    'HOME_TEAM_WIN_PERCENTAGE',
    'AWAY_TEAM_WIN_PERCENTAGE',
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_GAMES_AT_HOME',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_GAMES_AWAY',
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_WINS_AT_HOME',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_WINS_AWAY',
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_LOSSES_AT_HOME',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_LOSSES_AWAY',
    'HOME_TEAM_WIN_PERCENTAGE_AT_HOME',
    'AWAY_TEAM_WIN_PERCENTAGE_AWAY',
    'HOME_TEAM_WIN/LOSS_STREAK',
    'VISITOR_TEAM_WIN/LOSS_STREAK',
    'HOME_TEAM_WIN/LOSS_STREAK_AT_HOME',
    'VISITOR_TEAM_WIN/LOSS_STREAK_AWAY',
    'AVG_POINTS_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_CONCEDED_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_CONCEDED_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_ASSISTS_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_ASSISTS_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FGPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FGPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FTPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FTPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FG3PCT_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FG3PCT_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_REB_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_REB_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_CONCEDED_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_ASSISTS_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FGPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FTPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FG3PCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_REB_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_CONCEDED_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_ASSISTS_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FGPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FTPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FG3PCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_REB_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'FOUNDATION_HOME',
    'FOUNDATION_VISITOR'
    ])

    data_normalized[[
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_GAMES',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_GAMES',
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_WINS',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_WINS',
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_LOSSES',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_LOSSES',
    'HOME_TEAM_WIN_PERCENTAGE',
    'AWAY_TEAM_WIN_PERCENTAGE',
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_GAMES_AT_HOME',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_GAMES_AWAY',
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_WINS_AT_HOME',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_WINS_AWAY',
    'HOME_TEAM_TOTAL_LOSSES_AT_HOME',
    'AWAY_TEAM_TOTAL_LOSSES_AWAY',
    'HOME_TEAM_WIN_PERCENTAGE_AT_HOME',
    'AWAY_TEAM_WIN_PERCENTAGE_AWAY',
    'HOME_TEAM_WIN/LOSS_STREAK',
    'VISITOR_TEAM_WIN/LOSS_STREAK',
    'HOME_TEAM_WIN/LOSS_STREAK_AT_HOME',
    'VISITOR_TEAM_WIN/LOSS_STREAK_AWAY',
    'AVG_POINTS_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_CONCEDED_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_CONCEDED_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_ASSISTS_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_ASSISTS_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FGPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FGPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FTPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FTPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FG3PCT_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FG3PCT_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_REB_LAST_4_GAMES_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_REB_LAST_4_GAMES_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_CONCEDED_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_ASSISTS_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FGPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FTPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_FG3PCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_REB_LAST_4_GAMES_AT_HOME_HOME_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_POINTS_CONCEDED_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_ASSISTS_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FGPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FTPCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_FG3PCT_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'AVG_REB_LAST_4_GAMES_AWAY_VISITOR_TEAM',
    'FOUNDATION_HOME',
    'FOUNDATION_VISITOR'
    ]] = scaled_df

    result = data_normalized.isna().sum()
    result.to_csv('nan_counts2.csv', header=['NaN_count'])
    return data_normalized

I checked the csv file that is generate in the beginning of the normalize_data function and there are no NaN, but in the csv file at the end of the function there are around 7000 lines with NaN values.
Am I doing some mistake when I am normalizing my data?
Also, I tried deleting the rows where Season is 2003 before merging the two dataframes and the problem doesn't happen.
#Import data from pkl files
    games = pd.read_pickle('cleaned_data/merged.pkl')
    teams = pd.read_pickle('cleaned_data/teams.pkl')
 
    games = games[games['SEASON'] != 2003]
    #Add foundation year of home team
    games = games.merge(teams[['TEAM_ID', 'YEARFOUNDED']], left_on='HOME_TEAM_ID', right_on='TEAM_ID', how='left')
    games['FOUNDATION_HOME'] = games['YEARFOUNDED']
    games.drop('TEAM_ID', axis=1, inplace=True)
    games.drop('YEARFOUNDED', axis=1, inplace=True)

I runned both versions while saving the resultant games dataframe to a csv file, and when comparing them I reached the conclusion that they are equal.
What can be causing this problem?

Possibly an index mismatch? What's the index on your training set?
